# How to unpack a string - created with sprintf - with fixed width in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, printf, pack, unpack

The following line with fixed with:

```
my $line = 'ATOM      1  P   CYT B   3      42.564 -34.232  -7.330  1.00105.08           P'
```

Is created with the following sprintf.

```
@entr = ( 'ATOM', '1', 'P', 'CYT', 'B', '3', '42.564', '-34.232', '-7.330', '1.00', '105.08', 'P' );
print sprintf("%-6s%5d  %-4s%3s %1s%4d    %8.3f%8.3f%8.3f%6.2f%6.2f          %2s\n",@newentr)
```

What I want to do is to **reverse** the process.
Namely with `$line` as input create the array that looks exactly like `@entr`.
How can I achieve that in Perl?

Comment: I'm getting a different line (`CYT` vs `C`).

Comment: @choroba: I updated `@entr`.

Comment: Having the two decimal numbers directly next to each other (`1.00105.08`) isn't very clear... is `$line` supposed to be human-readable?

Comment: @ialarmedalien: That's precisely why we need unpack. The column is defined by fixed with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [unpack](http://p3rl.org/unpack), or alternatively, a regex:

```
#                    %-6s%5d  %-4s%3s %1s%4d    %8.3f%8.3f%8.3f%6.2f%6.2f          %2s\n
my @rev_eng = unpack 'a6 a5 x2 a4 a3x1 a1 a4 x4 a8   a8   a8   a6   a6   x10       a2', $output;

my $reg = qr/^(.{6}) (.{5}) .. (.{4}) (...) . (.) (.{4}) .{4} (.{8}) (.{8}) (.{8}) (.{6}) (.{6}) .{10} (..)/x;
my @regex = $output =~ $reg;

s/^\s+|\s+$//g for @rev_eng, @regex;
```

In a template, `a` stands for string, `x` ignores the given number of bytes (spaces in this case).

Comment: how come the array Dumper shows entries with trailing spaces http://codepad.org/fu2usvIm